# How do I prevent subsubsections placed one after the other from creating a new page?

Tags: sectioning

I'm using subsubsections one after the other to have a nicely ordered list. The document is basically section -> subsection -> subsubsection where the subsubsections are listed items, e.g 4.1.1 and 4.1.2. If the list of subsubsections is too long however, it makes a new page so that there's big gaps in the document. How do I stop them from creating new pages.

The subsection occurs halfway on a page, with subsubsections beginning on the next page starting from A.

```
\subsection{Requirements}

\subsubsection{A}
\subsubsection{B}
\subsubsection{C}
\subsubsection{D}
\subsubsection{E}
\subsubsection{F}
\subsubsection{G}
\subsubsection{H}
\subsubsection{I}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show us a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: This is no MWE, this is a fragment!

Comment: presumably you real document has text in the subsections, the page breaking is then completely different, the fragment doesn't work as latex prevents page breaking after a subsection heading so all the subsections are forced into an unbreakable block as there is no text where a page break can happen

Comment: “I'm using subsubsections one after the other to have **a nicely ordered list**”?!?

Comment: Wouldn't nested `enumerate` or `description` environments be a better way to achieve what you want?

Comment: @Seamus I need to have two more numbers in front of the item to indicate the section and the subsection. Can I do that using `enumerate`?

Comment: Yes, like this: `\begin{enumerate}[\thesubsection.1] \item A \item B ... \item I \end{enumerate}` -- it will automatically put the subsection number in front of the enumeration counter, separated by a dot.